# jQuery post data including html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

```
TestJSON = {
    Test: function (eventId) {
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.Content = 'Hello<br>world.';
        var data = $.toJSON(obj); //JSON.stringify(obj);
        alert(data);
        $.post(SvConstant.GetBaseUrl() + "/Services/PageHandler/TestJSON.aspx?type=TestJSON", { 'data': data }, TestJSON.Test_OnSuccess, "json");
    },

    Test_OnSuccess: function (cmdResult) {
        ...
    } }
```

The code snippet above cannot post data to server because it contains 
 tag. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You can encode the data in JavaScript "escape(string)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
obj.Content = escape('Hello<br>world.');
```

Comment: How to restore it in C#.NET without replacing characters manually?

Comment: Can use HttpUtility.UrlDecode to restore it on server.Thanks.